# Will PHP's strip_tags work with svg format?

Tags: php, svg, strip-tags

Will PHP's strip_tags() work with svg format? I am looking for a way to find only the text and to clear all other content.

Comment: Did you ever tried it? To get text from some specific XML-elements use a parser…

Comment: It works with XML, I assume it will work with SVG too.

Comment: You should try it first. If you encounter any problems you canot solve yourself, than use StackOverflow to look for an answer.

Comment: I was just looking for an answer so I would not waste my time.

Comment: Now you're wasting everybody else's time

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will work with any HTML or XML string.